# How to get nodes with unique properties in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

In Dr.who dataset that is available in neo4j, I want to get all the nodes having properties `character`. The cypher query I am using is :-

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE 
HAS(n.property) 
RETURN n
```

But this query, even returns me some nodes which has `character` and other property keys too (as shown in http://imgur.com/ujizTZj) but I want to get nodes having only `character` property key only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Neo4j 2.2+, forget the "START" clause and use the "MATCH" instead.

Also, for your use case I don't think before 2.2 it is possible, but in 2.2+ you can do :

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE HAS(n.character) 
AND size(keys(n)) = 1
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Appreciated.